# Google Map api return 400 Bad request

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3

My code

```
<?php
$origin = $_POST['origin'];
$address = explode("\n",$_POST['addresses']);
$address = implode("|",$address);
$data = array('origin'=>$origin,
          'destination'=>$origin,
          'waypoints'=>'optimize:true|'.$address,
          'key'=>'MYAPIKEY',
          'sensor'=>'false');
$data = http_build_query($data);
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?".$data;
echo file_get_contents($url);
?>
```

$_POST['origin'] = "Frimurarvägen 20, Skärholmen"

$_POST['addresses'] = "Vasagatan 7, 111 20 Stockholm\nKungsträdgårdsgatan 20, 111 47 Stockholm\nUlvsundavägen 160, 168 67 Bromma\nHuvudstagatan 2A, 171 44 Solna"

What i tried: 
Urlencode the post param.
str_replace the space with %20

Comment: try changing the permission

Comment: The problem's probably with characters like `ä` and `å`.  Read https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/web-service-best-practices#BuildingURLs

Comment: @duncan when i use the link in the browser .. it return a result.. but with file_get_content it doesn't

Comment: @rupesh what permission?

Comment: if ur using lamp go to var folder in cmd promt type sudo chmod -R 777 'var/path/path/etc'

Comment: directory permission.. its not the problem!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Google Map api doesn't accept å ä ö

Comment: Why don't you use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) with your address strings in order to solve this issue?

Comment: @xomena if i encode the full address. google map api won't accept it